# Insert data from table into a new one with condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Okay, so this has been bugging me the whole day. I have two tables (e.g original_table and new_table). The new table is empty and I need to populate it with records from original_table given the following conditions:

- Trip duration must be at least 30 seconds
- Include only stations which have at least 100 trips starting there
- Include only stations which have at least 100 trips ending there

The duration part is easy, but I find it hard to filter the other two conditions.
I tried to make two temporary tables like so:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE start_stations AS(
  SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT start_station_id FROM `dataset.original_table`
                WHERE duration_sec >= 30
                GROUP BY start_station_id 
                HAVING COUNT(start_station_id)>=100
                AND COUNT(end_station_id)>=100) as arr
);
CREATE TEMP TABLE end_stations AS(
  SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT end_station_id FROM `dataset.original_table`
                WHERE duration_sec >= 30
                GROUP BY end_station_id 
                HAVING COUNT(end_station_id)>=100
                AND COUNT(start_station_id)>=100) as arr
);
```

And then try to insert in the new_table like this:

```
INSERT INTO `dataset.new_table` 
SELECT a.* FROM `dataset.original_table` as a, start_stations as ss,
end_stations as es
WHERE a.start_station_id IN UNNEST(ss.arr)
AND a.end_station_id IN UNNEST(es.arr)
```

However, this does not provide me the right answer. I tried to make a temprary function to clean up the data, but I didnt go far. :(

Here's a sample of the table:

```
trip_id|duration_sec|start_date|start_station_id|  end_date|end_station_id|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
afad333|         231|2017-12-20|             210|2017-12-20|           355|
sffde56|          35|2017-12-12|             355|2017-12-12|           210|
af33445|         333|2018-10-27|             650|2018-10-27|           650|
dd1238d|         456|2017-09-15|             123|2017-09-15|           210|
dsa2223|         500|2017-09-15|             210|2017-09-15|           123|
                                                                        ...
```

I will be very thankful If you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `UNNEST()`. How is that working at all?

Comment: That is GCP BigQuery SQL syntax.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use the `mysql` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what my problem was. Since I must filter out stations where 100 trips started AND ended, doing it the way I did before was wrong.

The current answer for me was this:

```
INSERT INTO dataset.new_table 

WITH stations AS (
 SELECT start_station_id, end_station_id FROM dataset.original_table
 GROUP BY start_station_id, end_station_id
 HAVING count(start_station_id)>=100
 AND count(end_station_id)>=100
)


SELECT a.* FROM dataset.original_table AS a, stations as s
WHERE a.start_station_id = s.start_station_id
AND a.end_station_id = s.end_station_id
AND a.duration_sec >= 30
```

This way I am creating only one WITH clause which filters only start **AND** end stations, by the given criteria.
As easy as it looks, obviously my brain needs a rest sometimes and a start with a new perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Approach should be

```
with major_stations as(
select start_station_id station_id
from trips
group by start_station_id
having count(*) > 100
union 
select end_station_id station_id
from trips
group by end_station_id
having count(*) > 100
)
select *
from trips
where start_station_id in (select station_id from major_stations)
and trip_duration > 30
```

There may be some easy way, but this is first approach I think of.

Comment: I might be wrong, but trying it this way, I got only "stations which have at least 100 trips starting there" filtered but not the "ending" ones

Comment: Check query after union, I am taking all stations where trips ending with at least 100 trips as well.